# Openshift pods stuck in Init:0/1 status

Tags: openshift

I am deploying microservices in my openshift cluster but I can see out of 90 microservices nearly 10 got stuck in Init:0/1 status. Is there a way to troubleshoot the issue??

Comment: a good starting point would be checking the events for the deployment replica set pod and namespace in general. also, check if you have enough allocatable resources for the application. could help if you'd add for starts the yaml files of the microservices

Comment: ```for i in $(oc get pods); do oc describe pod $i;done``` looking at the `describe` output, will give you a starting point as to what happened. After that you can look at the logs with `oc logs <your pod>`. Please post that information for at least one of the containers here, for better help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web page UI.

Go to your developer tab, and go to project.
There you should see the recent events in your project where the errors related to the 0/1 pods stuck state should appear. For me it was something like

`Error creating: pods "xxxx" is forbidden: exceeded quota: project-quota, requested: requests.memory=500Mi, used: requests.memory=750Mi, limited: requests.memory=1Gi`

So that meant that my project was attempting to have 1.25Gi of memory when 1Gi was the limit

In this case I went down to project quotas in my project screen.

and saw something like this in yaml format:

```yaml
spec:
  hard:
    file-share-dr-off.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage: xGi
    file-share-dr-on.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage: xGi
    limits.cpu: 'x'
    limits.memory: 1Gi
    pods: 'x'
    requests.cpu: 'x'
    requests.memory: 1Gi
    vsan.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage: xGi
```

So I increased `limits.memory` and `requests.memory` to 2Gi for my project quota and hit save.
After that the pod errors got fixed.
And deployment went from 0/1 to 1/1 pods.